# Angular 2 Template not updating

Tags: angular, promise

I'm new to Angular 2 and attempting to get a simple project off the ground. It's running inside an embedded Electron browser, if that's at all relevant.

Basically, I just want to call a list of colonists from a service and print them to the page once the call is resolved. However, even though the promise resolves (I've logged out the output to console upon success), the template refuses to update.

I know my syntax is (mostly) correct, because before switching to the mock $Promise, I just set the value directly in ngOnInit() and it displayed just fine.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Here is my main App Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Colonist } from './models/colonist';
import { ColonistService } from './services/colonist.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [ColonistService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title: string;
    colonists: Colonist[];

    constructor(private colonistService: ColonistService) {
        this.title = "Steel Saviors";
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getColonists();
    }

    getColonists(): void {
        this.colonistService.getAll()
        .then(colonists => {
            console.log("GOT IT: ", colonists);
            this.colonists = colonists;
            console.log("THIS: ", this);
        });
    }

}
```

My App Module:

```js
// Modules
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core"
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

// Components
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { CharacterCreationComponent } from './components/character-creation/character-creation.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      CharacterCreationComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My App HTML Template:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<li *ngFor="let colonist of colonists">
  {{ colonist.firstName }}
</li>
```

My Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Colonist } from '../models/colonist';

import { COLONISTS } from '../mocks/mock-colonists';

@Injectable()
export class ColonistService {

    getAll(): Promise<Colonist[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(COLONISTS);
    }    
}
```

And my mock data:

```js
import { Colonist } from '../models/colonist';

export const COLONISTS: Colonist[] = [
    {firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Appleton', age: 21},
    {firstName: 'Brandi', lastName: 'Brown', age: 25},
    {firstName: 'Clay', lastName: 'Cassius', age: 32}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, actually. I forgot one crucial piece of information (my apologies): I'm running the code inside Electron, which appears to require an NgZone run() to refresh from external elements (such as promises).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

Comment: I see, this is good info for me as I am starting on electron too :D

Answer (score 1):

My original guess is the javascript crashed because `colonists` is undefined when the page is loaded.

So I suggest the following modification:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<ul *ngIf="colonists">
<li *ngFor="let colonist of colonists">
  {{ colonist.firstName }}
</li>
</ul>
```

However, I created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xRMCcB and it work without the above change.

So your code, at least those portion posted, seems working.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention a crucial factor -- I'm running this code inside of Electron, which appears to be the source of the issue.

Please see my answer below. :)